# Import React-Password-Strength

Tags: reactjs

For business needs, I would like to customize this component: https://github.com/mmw/react-password-strength

Is there a way to insert it into my code without importing it from node_modules?

I mean, I want to avoid:

```
import ReactPasswordStrength from 'react-password-strength'
```

and do something like:

```
import MyReactPasswordStrength from '../common/react-password-strength'
```

Comment: copy folder from node_modules/react-password-strength to ../common and use

Comment: already tried to work only, but not executed

Comment: If you're going to take someone else's work, make sure you have a legal right to do so. I'm not sure what licence that module was published under but you need to be careful about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you just have to import the [src folder](https://github.com/mmw/react-password-strength/tree/master/src) from the repository to your own project. In your case, create a new folder with the name `react-password-strength` in the `common` folder. Also, copy the style.css file from the `src` folder in the same location.

Then you can link to the folder with the import into your code as you have described.

Comment: Have you installed modules own packages?

Comment: I think I solved it, I was wrongly importing the only folder I had to import ... it was enough to import only the contents of the src directory and I did a rebuild of npm start

Answer (score 0):

try to take the file  his name index src/index.js that found in `react-password-strength/src/index.js` and copy don forget copy CSS because he imports them in the index
and doesn't forget to install this dependency## Heading ##
zxcvbn  and props-type' and take the rename the file index to the react-password-strength.js  but the where you want to store it  tell me if work or not

Comment: I think I solved it, I was wrongly importing the only folder I had to import ... it was enough to import only the contents of the src directory and I did a rebuild of npm start